# NodeJS/Nodemon - reset environment variable on server restart

Tags: node.js, bash, nodemon

I'm running a Node/Express app with Nodemon... I have an environment variable that I want to reset every time Nodemon restarts the app, but I find that although the reset script runs, the environment variable is not accessible in the running app.  Let me break this down...

First off, I'm running this on my Mac.

I have a `bash` script in my app that is set up to get the current datetime and `export` it as an environment variable -

`env_publich.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash
BUILD_DATE=`node ./scripts/version_info/get_build_date.js`
export BUILD_DATE=$BUILD_DATE
echo Setting environment variables: BUILD_DATE="$BUILD_DATE"
```

(`get_build_date.js` just returns a simple JS `new Date()` object)

From the `package.json`, the `start` script is straightforward:

```
"start": "nodemon app.js"
```

And in my `nodemon.json`, I would ideally like to call the `bash` script to generate the new environment variable - in my imagination, this would do the trick:

```
"events": {
    "start": "source env_public.sh"
},
"env": {
    "NODE_ENV": "development",
    "PORT": 3000
}
```

But it does not. Although `NODE_ENV` and `PORT` are available as expected, `BUILD_DATE` is not available to `app.js`, although the script has run (and the value can be seen in the environment if a append `&& env` to the Nodemon `start` event).

I would guess that this has something to do with the relationship of parent/child processes, but this is not a topic that I'm familiar with... if I call `source env_public.sh && nodemon app.js` in the NPM `start` script, the value is accessible in `app.js`, but it does not update on Nodemon restarts. Ok, well I kind of get that, but it *seems* to me like `app.js` is a child of Nodemon, since it inherits the two `env` variables defined above... perhaps I am using the wrong command in `nodemon.json`?

In a nutshell, is there anyway that I can dynamically reset an environment variable when using Nodemon and make that new value available to the running app?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way is to set the environment variable `BUILD_DATE` directly inside your JavaScript code.

```
process.env.BUILD_DATE = new Date().toString();
console.log(process.env.BUILD_DATE);
```

Comment: Yes, that's true... but I'm trying to mimic my production environment where that value is set dynamically as an environment variable to record the time that the server is initially started. So every time Nodemon restarts my local server, I want it to mimic the behavior of my production environment. It's not a big deal, I'm just trying to be consistent across environments.